# Inavlid timestamp Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have Ship_Date as 12/14/2013 20:27 and defined as varachar datatype in the source table.How can I convert this to timestamp format and load as is 12/14/2013 20:27?I'm using  CAST (SHIP_DATE AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYHH:MI:SS') AS SHIP_DATE but terdata is throwing invalid timestamp error.Please help in resolving the issue

Answer (score 2):

You were missing the `B` indicating a *blank/space* in your original cast. But Teradata casts chokes on a single digit month. You can add a leading zero using a RegEx:

```
Cast(RegExp_Replace(SHIP_DATE,'\b([\d])\b', '0\1') AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT'dd/mm/yyyyBhh:mi')
```

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't even notice the dang B was missing.

Answer (score 1):

select to_timestamp('12/14/2013 20:27','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI');

Comment: sel     to_timestamp(SHIP_DATE ,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') 
 FROM TABLE1 ..I tried this way but throwing error month of the year must be two digits long.

Comment: You need to lpad a leading zero for SHIP_DATE values having months 1..9

Comment: I've always wondered why `DD` can handle a single digit day while `MM` cannot handle a single digit month.

Comment: There's just one stupid issue with TO_TIMESTAMP, it always returns a TIMESTAMP(6)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your cast as you have it written is you are telling Teradata you have seconds in your string when you don't. You can use:

```
select cast ('12/14/2014 20:27' as TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI')
```

However, this still won't handle single digit months.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the empty space between 2013 and 20 and the missing zeros for the seconds.
I did oreplace to remove the space and concatenation and it worked.

```
SELECT
CAST (
( OREPLACE('12/14/2013 20:27', ' ','') ||':00')
AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYHH:MI:SS'
) AS SHIP_DATE
```

And the result is below:

[image]

Comment: Directly applying a matching `FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYbHH:MI'` is much simpler :-) Of course, this fails on single digit month/day, too.